# Insert (Add) a new item to a knockout viewmodel mapped by the knockout mapping plugin?

Tags: knockout.js, insert, mapping, addition

I've got a question. How do you insert a new item to a mapped object by knockout mapping plugin?

```
var ctrlVm = {
        oJsonFromServer: {},
        Init: function () {
            $.getJSON('Sample/GetJson', function (data) {
                ctrlVm.oJsonFromServer = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                ko.applyBindings(ctrlVm.oJsonFromServer);
            });
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        ctrlVm.Init();
    });
```

Where oJsonFromServer is taken on server.

The JSON from server:

```
{  
"id":1,
"ArrayCollection":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "idParent":1,
     "name":"Steve",
     "ArrayCollectionChild":[  
        {  
           "id":1,
           "idParent":1,
           "ArrayCollectionChild_Child":[  
              {  
                 "id":1,
                 "idParent":1,
                 "name":"Bob"
              }
           ]
        }
     ],
     "ArrayCollectionChild2":[  
        {  
           "id":1,
           "idParent":1,
           "name":"Phill"
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to add a new item to ArrayCollection and it will add ArrayCollectionChild, ArrayCollectionChild_Child and so on. How can I do that?

You do not need to give a full reply. Please just give me an idea. Once you have mapped a json object from a server how we can add/insert new items to it? Manually? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Thanks.

**Edit: What I am doing. I am looking the easiest way to do it. ** (Just the basic code)

```
function ArrayCollectionChild(id, idParent, name){
    var self = this;
    self.ChildCollection = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.idParent = ko.observable(idParent);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);                  
}

function ArrayCollectionChild_Child(id, idParent, name){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.idParent = ko.observable(idParent);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);          
}

function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.ArrayCollection = ko.observable([]);

    self.addArrayCollectionChild = function(){
         var objToAdd = new ArrayCollectionChild(1,1,"Bob");
         self.ArrayCollection.push(objToAdd); // Object
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what is your question about - what is "manually" and what is "automatically"? After your json is mapped to view model, your `ArrayCollection` becomes an observable array and you can push items to it in usual manner.

Comment: Hi. Yes. But I have to create a function (class) object to map. For instance: obj.someArrayObservable.push(new ObjectSampleModel { id: 1, name: "Bill"}); It means do the push "manually" we need to type all properties. A better approach would be: obj.someArrayObservable.AddWithDefaultValues() or something like that. So knockout would recognize the observable and persist all collections. I am not sure whether knockout do it. Got it? Thanks.